# Prove integral converges depending on $\alpha$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I know that the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{e}} \left(\frac{1}{x \log^2(x)}\right)^\alpha dx$$

converges for $0 < \alpha \leq 1$, and diverges for $\alpha > 1$. How can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is a natural substitution to impose?

Comment: I was thinking $log(x) = u$, leaving the integral: $\int \left(\frac{1}{e^u u^2} \right)^\alpha e^udu$, but this one is equally difficult

Comment: $$\int_0^{1/3}(\log(x))^{-2\alpha}\cdot x^{-1}\cdot x^{-\alpha+1}\,dx \stackrel{y=\log(x)}{\Rightarrow} ??$$

Comment: Written that way $$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{e}} \left(\frac{1}{x \log^2(x)}\right)^\alpha dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} y^{-2\alpha} e^{y ( -\alpha +1)}  dy$$ with $y=\log(x)$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$\int_0^{1/e} (1/(x (\ln x)^2))^t dx$ diverges for $t&gt;1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645788/int-01-e-1-x-ln-x2t-dx-diverges-for-t1)